# Running unit test class from VSCode

Tags: unit-test, vs-code

I am new to **VSCode**.

The **Org** is setup in **VSCode**.

**ForceCode**, **vforce**, **Salesforce CLI Integration** and some other extensions installed in the **VSCode**.

**Org** is authorized. I am able to save my changes in the **Org** using **VSCode**.

I was trying to run the unit test class using **VSCode**.

When I right-click in a blank area in the test class, I see following pop-up menu:

[image]

I tried browsing the main menus of **VSCode** to see if there is an option to run the test classes but not able to find any.

I have the option to run the test class using developer console, is there any way I can run the test class from `VSCode` itself and see results?

Is there any extension which is needed to run test classes?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but If you are from java background then try (Intellij + illuminated cloud 2) as plugin. The plugin is a paid plugin, but it combines  development, deployment, log analysis,  test run , anonymous apex and many more under one window, which is really helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have three options for this.

1. Run Invoke Apex Tests Command

   [image]

You will be prompted for a Test class name or Run all.

[image]

2. From Test Window

**Edit:** Added screenshot for Test Window.

[image]

You will find a list of all unit tests there.
     [image]

3. From test class itself.

   a. 'Run All Test' button above the definition of Test Class.

   b. 'Run Test' button above the definition of the test method.

   [image]

Comment: I am able to run test cases using option 1.
There is no test classes in my **APEX TESTS** window.

I am not able to see **Run AllTests** and **Run Test** button on the test class.
If I can see such buttons on the test class, it will be quick to run test cases.

Comment: @वरुण I have edited the post and added screenshot for the Test Window

Comment: I was already checking in the Test window, but there were no test cases there. Clicked on **Refresh** button also but the cases were not getting loaded.

Comment: try refreshing the window

Comment: Your last option seems to be depend on a particular extension.  I used to have this available, but after reinistalling I don't.  The key question is which extension adds this functionality.

Comment: @user6856 This is part of Salesforce Extension Pack

Comment: @rahul gawale  Nope.  I have the salesforce extension pack.  I'm starting to thing this might be more obscure of a problem than the extensions installed.  My previous install was configured with a dx hub created when I took a course last year.  The Hub no longer exists, and I was not using it.  But maybe even just having it configured enables certain parts of the extension pack.   The other thing I have lost is auto deploy on save.   That is something that made sense when connected to a scratch org, but makes no sense to have enabled when using a sandbox.

Comment: have tried to update the SF CLI? @user6856

Comment: It turns out I needed the following line in my settings.json file:

    "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home": "/opt/zulu11.35.15-ca-jre11.0.5-linux_x64/",

Comment: very thorough answer, well written. thanks @rahulgawale